# Is there any callback to ionic sidemenu when it is closed?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic project with sidemenu. I want to load the content only after the sidemenu transition is finished. Then, I wrote the follow snipet:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen();
}, function (val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```

However, my app returns "true" at the moment I tap to open the menu, and returns "false" at the moment I tap to close the menu. I would like to receive "false", or "true" only after the transition finished.

Someone can help me please? Thanks alot!!!

Comment: It's not perhaps the nicest way, but you could look at how long the CSS transition is setup to take which hides the menu, then do a `$timeout` angular call specifying that same timeout in ms and perform the logic you require. A hack, but the timing should be closely consistent regardless of screen resolutions or devices.

Comment: Thanks @GONeale, but I really would to avoid solutions with timers.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
        return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.getOpenRatio();
    },
                function (ratio) {
                    if (ratio == 0) {
                        //your code
                    }
                    //if (ratio == 1) {
                        //your code
                    //}
                });
```

Comment: Thanks @Jérôme, I've tried. This show me "0" and "1" , but not at the end of the transitions.